# Identification of Data Types in C / C++

Tags: c++

I have used the below simple code:

```
#define char long long int
int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(char) << endl;
    // want to use char as a 1 byte data type
}
```

I have the idea that if `#define` is used in a program then definition is expanded in the compile time. But, now if I want to use `char` as a 1 byte data types then what should I do ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place anyway?

Comment: I just want to identify the use of #define in any program.

Comment: Then you want a tool that reads the code file and lists all the #define lines.

Comment: Suggested reading: [The XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AbdullaAlSun _"I just want to identify the use of #define in any program."_ You better just don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**17.6.4.3.1 Macro names [macro.names]**

> 1 A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header.
> 2 A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords.

So whatever you do after your define, program semantics is undefined anyway.

**UPDATE**:
Technically behavior is undefined only when you include any header from standard library. You seem to do so, as you are using cout. Anyway not including any standard header is a very heavy constraint.

The previous standard quotation is preceded with:

> 17.6.4.3 Reserved names [reserved.names]
>
> 1 The C ++ standard library reserves the following kinds of names:
> — macros
> — global names
> — names with external linkage
> 2 If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.

Comment: One should add that this is true in the OP's case because he uses `std::cout` and thus must use the standard library (unless his `cout` is actually something completely different :)). Technically, the standard actually allows redefining `char` if your program doesn't use the standard library. Of course, you should never even think about doing so anyway.

Comment: @user2079303: The entire section 17 is only about the standard library. Specifically, §17.6.4.1/1 says: *"This section describes restrictions on C++ programs that use the facilities of the C++ standard library."*

Comment: @ChristianHackl thanks for clarifying. It's now in the answer too, so I shall remove my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
#undef char
```

and after that, you can use char as you want.

But it's really dangerous to redefine keyword with macro.

Answer (score 1):

Once you `#define` something, it stays defined to that value for the rest of the compilation unit.

During a specific compilation unit, you can undo your `#define` with an `#undef`.

I'm sure you don't need to be told that using `#define` to change a keyword's behaviour is pernicious.

Comment: adjective: pernicious

    synonyms: harmful, damaging, destructive, injurious, hurtful, detrimental, deleterious, dangerous, adverse, inimical, unhealthy, unfavorable, bad, evil, baleful, wicked, malign, malevolent, malignant, noxious, poisonous, corrupting;